# Stream not updated in another stream listen function

Tags: flutter, dart

I have two streams, I want to put data in the second stream when there are new data in the first one.

I have my class A, in the constructor I put the integer 1 in the stream `a`, and I listen this stream, when there are new data, I put the integer 4 in the stream `b`.

```java
class A {
  Stream<int> a = BehaviorSubject<int>();
  Stream<int> b = BehaviorSubject<int>();

  A() {
    a = getDataA();

    a.listen((data) {
      b = getDataB();
    });
  }

  getDataA() {
    var _tmp = BehaviorSubject<int>();
    _tmp.add(1);
    return _tmp.stream;
  }

  getDataB() {
    var _tmp = BehaviorSubject<int>();
    _tmp.add(4);
    return _tmp.stream;
  }
}
```

And the widget that used the stream :

```java
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: objecta.b,
      builder: (BuildContext ctx, AsyncSnapshot<int> snap) {
        return Text((snap.data ?? -1).toString());
      },
    );
  }
```

The widget displays -1, instead of 4.

Comment: so you have to call `add` on stream B inside the callback you pass to `listen` method - `a.listen((data) => b.add(...));`

Comment: but, actually i would use a `map()` method to change the values of your original `A` stream- so no need for second `BehaviorSubject`, no need for `listen()` method etc

Answer (score 1):

You are not actually updating the stream but create a new one every time.

Do it this way instead:

```
class A {
  Stream<int> a = BehaviorSubject<int>();
  Stream<int> b = BehaviorSubject<int>();

  A() {
     a.listen((data) {
       b.sink.add(data);
     });
  }
}
```